# Android http post to php script

Tags: php, android, http

I am using the following code to post data to my server

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.kizikstudios.com/wltbo/new_score.php");


                    try {
                        // Add your data
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "harry"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("score", "12345"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "***"));
                        HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);

                        httppost.addHeader(entity.getContentType());
                        httppost.setEntity(entity);

                        // Execute HTTP Post Request
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        String feedback = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                        feedback.length();

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
```

The server is receiving the post request but it says that the size is zero bytes, and my database never gets changed. In case it is needed here is the server side script.

```
<?
//****Made by: Jeroen den Haan***Alias's: jeroen84 / Jer'ul****
include_once ("_data.php");
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn);

if ($pass==$add_pass) {

if ($u_user==1) {

    $sql3 = "SELECT name FROM $db_table ORDER BY name";
    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
    while($r = mysql_fetch_object($result3)) 
{
    $tmp = "{$r->name}";
    if ($name==$tmp) {
        $n_exist=1;

    }
}
if ($n_exist==1) {
    $sql1 = "UPDATE $db_table SET score='$score' WHERE name=\"$name\"";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
} else {
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO $db_table (name,score) VALUES (\"$name\",\"$score\")";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
}

} else {
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO $db_table (name,score) VALUES (\"$name\",\"$score\")";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
}

$sql2 = "SELECT id FROM $db_table ORDER BY score DESC";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

$num = 1;
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($result2))
{
$result = mysql_db_query($db_name,"SELECT * from $db_table WHERE id='{$r->id}'");
$resultArray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$did = $resultArray["id"];
$name = $resultArray["name"];
$score = $resultArray["score"];
if ($num>$sec_size) {
$sql3 = "DELETE FROM $db_table WHERE id='$did'";
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
}
$num++;
}
}

mysql_close ($conn);
?>
```

does anyone know why this would not work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did u try to use php script directly in your browser ? does it work?

Comment: Your script does not output / display / print anything .. how can it returns something to android client ...?

Comment: your php code is not catching the values which are getting from android.

Comment: Ok so I am a complete newby at php, I literally know nothing about it so I don't know how to check it using a browser or run a var_dump(). I do know that it doesn't output anything, there is a separate script for that, so I should remove the response part from the android code.

Answer (score 0):

Where are your variables in php file that are capturing post values from other script? Can you var_dump() those variables to see if you are getting any post values to your php script?